# format (pretty print) the content of a xml CDATA value in java

Tags: java, xml

I have some code that cleans up modified XML files. These XML files contain CDATA sections that contain valid HTML.
I want to parse the XML file and format the CDATA value such that it's readable, namely pretty output.
How can I do this, as using the "TransformerFactory" for pretty printing the whole XML file will not pretty print the CDATA.

I think I should parse and format the CDATA content value as XML content and then write it back in the CDATA node, but is that the correct way ?
Isn't there a way to tell the Transformer to also format the CDATA content as XML/HTML ?

Comment: I've implemented a library which supports pretty-printing within CDATA: https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDATA in XML is arbitrary character data.  By definition it does not need to follow rules for XML and character entities and so on.  An XML parser won't do anything to CDATA content because it is not supposed to.

You say that in your document the CDATA contains HTML.  Note that HTML is not XML!  (Unless it is the obsolete XHTML). HTML allows elements that are not closed, for one, and bare attributes without values for another.

You will need to take the CDATA from your XML and pass it to an HTML parser, perform the desired pretty-print transformation and then put it back in your XML document.

Comment: Thanks DSH, which HTML parser could I use (I prefer a default one that comes with java)...